# How to invoke @BeforeMethod block before @PostConstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-test-mvc

I am writing below Spring Unit test code.  Unit test @Before method is not getting executed. Since it is directly running @PostConstruct i am getting erorrs `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rate must be positive` because the default value is 0.00.  I want to set some value to request max limit so that postcontstruct block will go through smoothly.  what is wrong in my code?  Please help.

```
@Component
public class SurveyPublisher  {

    @Autowired
    private SurveyProperties surveyProperties;

    @PostConstruct
        public void init() {
            rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(psurveyProperties.getRequestMaxLimit());
        }

    }

    public void publish() {
        rateLimiter.acquire();
        // do something
    }

}
```

//Unit test class

```
public class SurveyPublisherTest  extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Mock
    SurveyProperties surveyProperties;

    @BeforeMethod   
    public void init() {
        Mockito.when(surveyProperties.getRequestMaxLimit()).thenReturn(40.00);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPublish_noResponse() {
        //do some test
    }

}
```

Comment: how are you running test method from your test class? I don't you are using any `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. are you sure your mocks got injected in your the class you are testing?

Comment: I have updated the test class..  it is extending `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`  run as TestNG Test .

Comment: The clean answer is to rewrite your `SurveyPublisher` to use constructor injection and also to inject the rate limiter, which will allow you to easily test those in your test case.

Comment: Create a `static` configuration class inside your test class. Create an `@Bean` method in there that returns the `SurveyProperties` just as you want them. You don't need a mock for this. Or depending on your test, don't use Spring and create the class and dependencies yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simple one worked.

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SurveyProperties.class)
    static class Config {
}


@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
        SurveyPublisherTest.Config.class })
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "com.test.survey.request-max-limit=1.00" })
public class SurveyPublisherTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

//Remove this mock
//@Mock
//SurveyProperties surveyProperties;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just realized it will always run `postConstruct` method before Junit callback methods cause spring takes the precedence. As explained in the documentation -

> if a method within a test class is annotated with @PostConstruct, that
>   method runs before any before methods of the underlying test framework
>   (for example, methods annotated with JUnit Jupiter’s @BeforeEach), and
>   that applies for every test method in the test class.

**Solution to you issue -**

1. As @chrylis commented above refactor your `SurveyPublisher` to use constructor injection to inject the rate limiter. So you can then easily test.
2. Inject Mock/Spy bean which is causing the problem
3. Create test config to give you the instance of the class to use as `@ContextConfiguration`

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class YourTestConfig {

       @Bean
       FactoryBean getSurveyPublisher() {
           return new AbstractFactoryBean() {
               @Override
               public Class getObjectType() {
                   return SurveyPublisher.class;
               }

               @Override
               protected SurveyPublisher createInstance() {
                   return mock(SurveyPublisher.class);
               }
           };
       }
   }
   ```